# Get selected images from DKAssests

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Using DKImagePickerController from selecting multiple images and videos from gallery. But only able to select images and videos from gallery, yet not able to get selected images from DKAssets and save to array. Spent more than a day.

Below is the code trying:

```
let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()


        pickerController.assetType = DKImagePickerControllerAssetType.AllAssets
        pickerController.allowsLandscape = false
        pickerController.allowMultipleTypes = true
        pickerController.sourceType = DKImagePickerControllerSourceType.Both
        pickerController.singleSelect = false

        // Clear all the selected assets if you used the picker controller as a single instance.
        //      pickerController.defaultSelectedAssets = nil

        pickerController.defaultSelectedAssets = self.assets

        pickerController.didSelectAssets = { [unowned self] (assets: [DKAsset]) in
            print("didSelectAssets")


    }
    self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true) {}
```

Please guide, thanks ion advance.

Comment: what have you done sofar?

Comment: you have to respond in time. so that you can get your answer.

Comment: posted above what i have tried so far, lots of googling done. sharing a link also that i was trying to follow.
https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController/issues/122

Comment: posted the answer below. check it and let me know if you face any problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function. it worked for me.

```
func showImagePickerWithAssetType
    (
    assetType: DKImagePickerControllerAssetType,
    allowMultipleType: Bool,
    sourceType: DKImagePickerControllerSourceType = [.Camera, .Photo],
    allowsLandscape: Bool,
    singleSelect: Bool) {

        let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()
        pickerController.assetType = assetType
        pickerController.allowsLandscape = allowsLandscape
        pickerController.allowMultipleTypes = allowMultipleType
        pickerController.sourceType = sourceType
        pickerController.singleSelect = singleSelect
        //          pickerController.showsCancelButton = true
        //          pickerController.showsEmptyAlbums = false
        //          pickerController.defaultAssetGroup = PHAssetCollectionSubtype.SmartAlbumFavorites

        // Clear all the selected assets if you used the picker controller as a single instance.
        //          pickerController.defaultSelectedAssets = nil
        pickerController.defaultSelectedAssets = self.assets

        pickerController.didSelectAssets = { (assets: [DKAsset]) in
            print("didSelectAssets")

            self.assets = assets
            if assets.count > 0 {
                self.cameramoment.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
                //self.cameramoment.titleLabel?.alpha = 50
                //self.cameramoment.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 184.0, blue: 214.0, alpha: 1.0)
            }
            else {
                //self.cameramoment.setImage( UIImage (named: "grey_camera_32x32"), forState: .Normal)
              self.cameramoment.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
              self.cameramoment.titleLabel?.alpha = 50
            }
            self.collectionview.reloadData()

        }

        if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .Pad {
            pickerController.modalPresentationStyle = .FormSheet;
        }

        self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true) {}
}
```

Call this function like this.

```
self.showImagePickerWithAssetType(DKImagePickerControllerAssetType.AllPhotos, allowMultipleType: true, allowsLandscape: true, singleSelect: false)
```

self.assets is defines as,

```
var assets: [DKAsset] = []
```

To get the image from DKAsset. try this.

```
for asset in assets {
  asset.fetchImageWithSize(requiredImageSize, completeBlock: { image, info in
            if let img = image {
              let fixOrientationImage=img.fixOrientation()
              cell.postmomentimage1.image = fixOrientationImage
            }
    })
}
```

Comment: crash at self.assets = assets

Comment: did you select a photo? cause it may return nil

Comment: put that self.assets = assets inside that if condition

Comment: if assets.count > 0 {
                //self.cameramoment.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
                //self.cameramoment.titleLabel?.alpha = 50
                //self.cameramoment.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 184.0, blue: 214.0, alpha: 1.0)
                print("count more than 0")
                
                self.assets = assets
            }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123687/discussion-between-ganesh-kumar-and-iphone-6).

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import DKImagePickerController

class addPhotoViewController: UIViewController {

var assets:[DKAsset] = []
var pickerController: DKImagePickerController!

@IBOutlet weak var selectedPhoto: UIImageView!

@IBAction func sec(_ sender: Any) {

    let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()
    pickerController.singleSelect = true

    pickerController.didSelectAssets = { (assets: [DKAsset]) in
        print("didSelectAssets")
        print(assets)
        for asset in assets {
            asset.fetchOriginalImage(true, completeBlock: { image, info in
                if let img = image {
                    let fixOrientationImage=img
                    print(fixOrientationImage)
                    print(info)
                    self.selectedPhoto.image = fixOrientationImage
                }
            })
        }
    }
    self.present(pickerController, animated: true) {}
   }
}
```